# SOAP : API's to use in java for Interoperatability

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

Question may be simple / asked many times.

Could not get the Correct answer (including google--yahoo).

Question : Which **DataType API's( List, Array ,String,int...) of Java / J2EE sdk** to  use for

SOAP messages so as the same can be **consumed by Other Languages ( eg : - php/.net/cfx/.....)**

with regards
karthik

Comment: In my opionion, it doesn't matter as long as you are not transfering proprietary objects. All in all, the representation matters. Data must be represented in XML/JSON format.

Comment: Always follow a contract-first approach. Create your WSDLs and XSDs, then generate the Java code (not vice-versa). In my experience this works best and forces you to develop a proper language independent interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you are limited as long as you don't make any circular data structures since those are not available in XML representation.

But it is in general usually easiest to keep your objects/types quite simple. I've for example has problem with XML structures deeper than 3 nodes when using kSOAP (older version).

Comment: >>Data must be represented in XML/JSON format.

>>easiest to keep your objects/types quite simple. I've for example has problem with XML structures deeper.

My existing apps in EJB3.0 are objects embedded in **Java Beans ( getter/setter of Data
types with  String,int,String Array,int Array,boolean,integers,date(util/sql) ).**

So what restriction would i have to apply for interoperability in Json/xml creation.


Ths same may be consumed in other languages ???

with regards
karthik